# How to combine values from one object to another with same value condition using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have here an array of objects that goes like this:

```
[
        {
            id: 1,
            subject_name : "Subject 1",
            revision_no : 1,
            revision_date : '2020/01/01'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            subject_name : "Subject 1",
            revision_no : 2,
            revision_date : '2020/01/02'
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            subject_name : "Subject 1",
            revision_no : 3,
            revision_date : '2020/01/03'
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            subject_name : "Subject 2",
            revision_no : 1,
            revision_date : '2020/01/05'
        }

    ]
```

and I want my expected output will be like this one below which combine all objects that have the same subject_name property and get their revision_date[nth] to single row:

```
[
        {
            id: 1,
            subject_name : "Subject 1",
            revision_no : 3,
            revision_date1: '2020/01/01',
            revision_date2: '2020/01/2',
            revision_date3: '2020/01/03',
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            subject_name : "Subject 1",
            revision_no : 3,
            revision_date1: '2020/01/05',
            revision_date2: '',
            revision_date3: '',
        },
    ]
```

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can match on `subject_name`. So, to get you started, let's call the first array `revisions`. You can loop over it using something like this:

```
revisions.forEach((revision) => {
  /* IMPLEMENT ME */
})`.
```

You need to create an output array too, so put this at the start:

```
let revisionsOut = [];
```

In your loop you want to determine whether or not an entry exists for a revision, so you could write this:

```
const findRevisionIndex = (newRevisions, revision) => {
  /**
   IMPLEMENT ME

   newRevisions is your new array, you need to loop over it
   and return the index of the entry if a match is found, or
   null/false if no match is found

   revision is an entry from your loop

   This will need a loop too
   */
};
```

If you don't get a match then you need to create a new entry.

Finally you need a function to insert a revision line (either in an empty entry or one that already has entries). It would be easier to store an array in the key `revision_date`, but if you have to use numbered keys, you could write:

```
const findNextRevisionNumber = (newRevisions, revisionIndex) => {
  /* IMPLEMENT ME */
};
```

You can then insert key-value pairs using this formula:

```
revisionsOut[revisionIndex]['revision' + revisionNumber] = date;
```

This is, obviously, a skeleton that you need to work on. It is much better for your learning journey if you do it. Breaking down the problem is half the battle. Good luck!